# Compile-time safety of differences in domain types vs data types - with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, type-safety

Imagine a simple CRUD database application that uses `bigint`/`Int64` as a standard type for all IDENTITY primary keys.

In this case, Foo and Bar participate in a many-to-one relationship:

```
class Foo {
    Int64 FooId { get; set; }
    Int64 ParentBarId { get; set; }
}

class Bar {
    Int64 BarId { get; set; }
}
```

It's clear that values of the `BarId` and `FooId` properties, while of the same data-type, have no domain reason to ever be compared or be assigned to each other, so this is meaningless:

```
Foo foo1 = ...
Foo foo2 = ...
Bar bar = ...
foo1.ParentBarId = bar.BarId; // ok...
foo2.ParentBarId = foo1.FooId; // programmer error!
```

This problem is similar to the "units" problem present in this and other languages where two values are considered compatible by the compiler (e.g. a `double` value representing inches in one object, but centimetres in another) even though they're incompatible.

I'm wondering if there is an idiomatic-C# solution to this problem, i.e. enforce compile-type data member incompatibility.

There does exist various C# Units libraries (e.g. https://github.com/objorke/QuantityTypes/tree/master/Source/QuantityTypes/Quantities) which solve this problem by making each actual quantity a `struct` with an internal normalized representation (e.g. SI). By adapting this approach, my domain model looks like this:

```
struct FooId { Int64 Value; }
struct BarId { Int64 Value; }

class Foo {
    FooId FooId { get; set; }
    BarId ParentBarId { get; set; }
}

class Bar {
    BarId BarId { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that this quickly becomes unwieldy as you need to dereference the `Int64 Value` property to do anything with it (though you can copy the value directly):

```
foo1.ParentBarId = bar.BarId; // okay...
foo2.ParentBarId = foo1.FooId; // this is now disallowed by the compiler, good!

databaseClient.GetBar( foo1.ParentBarId.Value ) // but this means extra typing if the `GetBar` method (perhaps generated by EF) expects `Int64` instead of `BarId`.
```

A workaround is to add `implicit` operator, but as `struct`s in .NET don't have inheritance it must be manually defined on every struct type, which defeats the saving-of-typing. Another problem with allowing implicit conversion is it means this becomes possible (if `to-Int64` and `from-Int64` implicit conversion is defined): `FooId > Int64 > BarId` - which defeats the point of trying to introduce domain value safety.

Assuming those problems are surmountable, is it possible to get this to interface with Entity Framework at all? This would require EF to simultaneously support the use of `struct` complex-types (not supported), flattening 1-member ("1-uple"?) complex-types to single column values at the persistence layer, and finally supporting this for primary-key columns (an added complexity).

Has anyone had luck trying to implement compile-time correctness of domain values using this or a similar approach?

Comment: One can of course opt to not expose foreign keys, but instead stick to navigation properties.